# Emulating LAN and WAN in a single Linux machine using containers

Tags: linux, docker, container

I want to test my data-plane application and I want to find out if there is a way using containers.

After I bring up a container with my app in it, can I direct all my machine-generated Internet traffic to the container, process that traffic in my application and send it back down to the host network namespace and out the physical interface (say, eth0)?

Example:

I access Facebook and all traffic (DNS/UDP, HTTPS/TCP) for this should go to my container app in the same machine, get processed by my application and then sent out via eth0. Return traffic from the Internet comes back into my app first and then sent to the host client (browser here).

Answer (score 0):

For the non-DNS TCP traffic - tell your app that the IP address of facebook is the ip address of your container. On your container run a TLS MITM proxy (previously this was called sslbump in squid but the current implementation is  called [peek-n-splice](https://wiki.squid-cache.org/Features/SslPeekAndSplice)).

Unless you are happy to click through the certificate warnings then you'll also need to establish your own certificate authority and install the CA cert in the CA certs database on the host where the client is running.

You'll need to set up your own DNS server and configure the zones to fake the DNS (I suspect this may be possible with pihole) or just override the DNS entries in the hosts file.

I suspect you will have a lot of learning to do on your journey to implementing this.

Comment: your own certificate authority, you can also use Let's Encrypt of ZeroSSL

Comment: erm, no. They won't issue you a certificate for Facebook.

Comment: Oops, yeah, didn't think about that

Comment: Sorry if I was not clear. I don't want to do deep packet inspection. The application really just takes a packet and shoves it back down to go the Internet and vice versa.

Comment: Packet? Not a stream? Then you probably need to decrypt the stream. I think you really need to explain what you mean by "process that traffic" and how it adds value to the process of accessing a site.